# error: invalid hook call Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use useNavigate to go to another page and also pass the serviceID in the path. Any ideas why I'm getting that error?

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();

const ProductCard = ({ props,product, ...rest }) => (
    <Card
  
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100%'
    }}
    {...rest}
  >
    <CardActionArea onClick={event => {navigate('app/service/'+product.serviceID)}}>
    
    <CardContent> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Base on [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you need to move your `useNavigate()` inside the component:**

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductCard = ({ props,product, ...rest }) => {
const navigate = useNavigate();  // <-- MOVE HERE
return (
    <Card
  
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100%'
    }}
    {...rest}
  >
    <CardActionArea onClick={event => {navigate('app/service/'+product.serviceID)}}>
    
    <CardContent> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear, hook must be called inside the component, never outside.

So `ProductCard` functional component must be rewrited in this way:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductCard = ({ props,product, ...rest }) => { //<-- curly brackets
   const navigate = useNavigate(); //<-- call useNavigate

   return ( //<-- html inside return
      <Card
  
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100%'
    }}
    {...rest}
  >
    <CardActionArea onClick={event => {navigate('app/service/'+product.serviceID)}}>
    
    <CardContent> ...
   );
}
```